# Clear corresponding text-input when dropdown 'no/other' value is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**CURRENT**: Dropdown choice of 'Yes/No'.

'Yes' = Show 'additional' dropdown/inputs to be entered

'No' = Hide 'additional' dropdown/inputs

---

**WANT**: I want to make it so if the user chooses 'Yes', then enters something into the 'additional' dropdowns/inputs, but then decides to switch their original answer back to 'No', make it clear the 'additional' values.

This is so when the form submits, i wont be carrying over any values in the POST that aren't needed.

HTML

```
<section><style>.required {color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold;position:absolute;}</style>
<div class="section_header">LNB INFORMATION</div>
                <label>Did you install an LNB?<span class="required">*</span>&nbsp;</label>
                <select class="DropdownClass" name="lnb_choice" id="lnb">
                    <option disabled selected value="">Select...  (Required)</option>
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="0">No</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <div class="LNBChoice DivElement1">
                    <select class="DropdownClass qrt" name="lnb_type" id="lnb_type">
                        <option value="">Type...</option>
                        <option value="3D2RBLNB">REV 3 LNB</option>
                        <option value="5D2RBLNB">REV 5 LNB</option>
                        <option value="SL3S4NR2">SWM3 LNB</option>
                        <option value="SL5S4NR2">SWM5 LNB</option>
                        <option value="SL5K4NR1">KAKU LNB</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="lnb_barcode" name="lnb_barcode" placeholder="LNB Serial..." class="scantype basic" />

                </div>
</section>
```

JS + Jquery 1.10.1

```
$(".DropdownClass").change(function () {

    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'lnb_choice') {
        var number = $(this).val();

        $('.LNBChoice').hide().slice( 0, number ).show();
    }
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ra1t9jfL/

**Additional issue**: This is all part of a ,
If there is an error, i return them back to this page, using &field=value on the url to return values to the corresponding text input boxes/dropdowns.

I am able to return the 'Yes' value to the dropbox, but it does not activate the 'Show additional jquery'.

So the user has to select, 'No' then back to 'Yes' for the 'additional' to show up.

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines before or after `$('.LNBChoice').hide().slice( 0, number ).show();`

```
$('#lnb_type').val('');
$('#lnb_barcode').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the additional fields when the user selects "No" from the first drop down, you can add this which will do that:

```
$('#lnb').change(function() {

    if($(this).val() === '0') {

        /* User selected "no" so reset the additional field values */ 
        $('#lnb_type').val('');
        $('#lnb_barcode').val('');
    }    
});
```

To initialise the form based on values passed from the query string of the URL (ie on return from error screen), you could take the following approach:

```
/* Add the following script to your page */
$(function() {

    /* 
    Access query string of url, remove preceding "?", and split
    query string by "&" to return an array of "field=value" sub-strings
    if any exist. Iterate the array of these sub-strings with forEach
    */ 
    location.search.slice(1).split('&').forEach(function(part){

        /* Split current sub-string by "=" to obtain name and value */
        var nameValue = part.split('=');
        var name = nameValue[0];
        var value = value[1];
​
        /* Select form element by name and initialise the value */
        $('[name="' + name + '"]').val(value);
    });
});
```